# Remove property for all objects in array

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to remove the `bad` property from every object in the array. Is there a better way to do it than using a `for` loop and deleting it from every object?

```
var array = [{"bad": "something", "good":"something"},{"bad":"something", "good":"something"},...];

for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
  delete array[i].bad;
}
```

Just seems like there should be a way to use `prototype`, or something. I don’t know. Ideas?

Comment: Does not matter, the other ways cannot get any less then linear O(n). Whatever you use, will require accessing all of your array elements

Comment: Prototype? How would that help? Or are all those objects instances of the same constructor and share a common value for `bad`?

Comment: @Bergi I wonder if they were referring to prototypeJS, or the `Array` prototype, which dystroy exemplified

Comment: I'm not sure you should store array.length in a variable before looping. I'm sure you'll see it's not worth the pain if you profile.

Comment: @dystroy Other than creating another local variable, what's the "pain"?

Comment: @ian more code to read. About prototype, it might be the each function.

Comment: The idea was to find a faster way, storing the length is generally faster. Unfortunately looks like O(n) is the only way to do this. Lame.

Comment: @ZackArgyle Yes, in the general case there's nothing faster.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

The only other ways are cosmetic and are in fact loops.

For example :

```
array.forEach(function(v){ delete v.bad });
```

Notes:

- if you want to be compatible with IE8, you'd need [a shim for forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). As you mention prototype, prototype.js also [has a shim](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Array/).
- `delete` is one of the worst ["optimization killers"](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#521-objects-that-are-in-hash-table-mode-aka-normalized-objects-dictionary-mode---objects-who-have-a-hash-table-as-a-backing-data-structure-are-not-simple-enumerables). Using it often breaks the performances of your applications. You can't avoid it if you want to really remove a property but you often can either set the property to `undefined` or just build new objects without the property.

Comment: Not much better than the loop if the loop is allowed to be "fake"-one lined too :P `for(var i = 0; i < array.length ) delete array[i].bad`

Comment: @Esailija Depends. I like to use `forEach` because I find the code more expressive (and because I stopped worrying about IE a long time ago).

Comment: Neither of them expresses "delete bad property of all objects in this array" in radically different way. `forEach` is generic and semantically meaningless by itself, like a `for` loop.

Comment: @Esailija I agree. That's why I precised it was "cosmetic". Isn't it clear in my answer ?

Comment: Unfortunate. I'll stick with the for loop which is generally faster than the forEach. And really...who cares about IE8. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, the for loop is faster. But really, you don't need to cache the array's length, the engine does a better job than you at this kind of optimizations.

Comment: Yeah I guess I'm just used to other programming languages that make a big performance increase.

Comment: `array.forEach(v => delete v.bad);`

Comment: not recommended, please see @piotr_cz https://stackoverflow.com/a/46839399/5452834 answered for the latest approach.

Comment: @FaiZalDong using `delete` should indeed be avoided but that other answer isn't an answer. It doesn't remove the properties but create a new object. I'll add a precision though for the cases such an approach is possible.

Comment: this is probably outdated now, is not working

Answer (score 455):

With ES6, you may deconstruct each object to create new one without named attributes:

```
const newArray = array.map(({dropAttr1, dropAttr2, ...keepAttrs}) => keepAttrs)
```

Comment: Applying to the initial problem it may be `const newArray = array.map(({ bad, ...item }) => item);`

Comment: This is very recommended since it doesn't modify the original array (immutable operations)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it returns a new array, instead of overwriting the existing one.

Comment: great answer but not working if property name contains dot(.) e.g. 'bad.prop'

Comment: @Amiraslan I'd use `// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars`

Comment: I am getting Error: converting circular structure to json, with this format. Any idea why?

Comment: What if the prop is dynamic? And u need to delete it on the fly?

Comment: @ИгорТашевски `.map(({ [prop]: _, ...keep }) => keep)`

Comment: @emile I think this is problem with typescript, when u ommit values with underscore.

Comment: @ИгорТашевски the `_` is just the new name of the local identifier, it could be anything, it's just ignored in the returned result.

Comment: The only problem with this in JS is that eslint freaks out on the unused `bad` variable.

Comment: this should be accepted answer imho

Comment: What is keepAttrs? Is it an arbitrary name? The name of the one attribute you want to keep?

Comment: @Reid yes it's a variable name for an object with attributes that will be kept (not removed)

Comment: Typescript gives an unused warning for the item to be dropped. It is healthier to use delete declare.

Comment: If anyone else was having a hard time converting this to json, try: `const newArray = array.map(({dropAttr1, dropAttr2, ...keepAttrs}) => keepAttrs._doc)`

Comment: What an absolutely brilliant use of destructuring and rest operators! I never would have thought it up myself.

Answer (score 35):

I prefer to use map to delete the property and then return the new array item.

```
array.map(function(item) { 
    delete item.bad; 
    return item; 
});
```

Comment: Be aware that this mutates original array

Comment: In this particular case explicit `return` statement would not be required

Comment: `array.forEach(v => delete v.bad);`

Answer (score 24):

You can follow this, more readable, not expectation raise due to key not found :

```
data.map((datum) => {
  return {
    'id':datum.id,
    'title':datum.login
  }
});
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! My objects had about 15 properties and I needed to keep 3.

Answer (score 22):

```
const arr = [
  {id: 1, name: 'user1', test: 'abc'},
  {id: 2, name: 'user2', test: 'xyz'},
];

const newArr = arr.map(({test, ...rest}) => {
  return rest;
});

console.log(newArr);
// ️ [{id: 1, name: 'User1'},  {id: 2, name: 'User2'}]
```

The function we pass to the Array.map method gets invoked with each element in the array.

We destructure the test property from each object and use the rest operator (...) to get the rest of the object's properties.

We return the rest of the object's properties from the function, practically excluding the test property.

```
const arr = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Tom', test: 'abc'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Bob', test: 'xyz'},
];

arr.forEach(object => {
  delete object['test'];
});

console.log(arr);
// ️ [{id: 1, name: 'Tom'}, {id: 2, name: 'Bob'}]
```

Comment: it return null to array

Comment: Please share your code sample if possible. It helps to understand issue

Answer (score 18):

If you use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/):

```
var strippedRows = _.map(rows, function (row) {
    return _.omit(row, ['bad', 'anotherbad']);
});
```

Answer (score 10):

For my opinion this is the simplest variant

```
array.map(({good}) => ({good}))
```

Comment: the question was about removing the bad, not keeping the good. If your objects have 10 fields to keep and one to remove, the above becomes really long to type.

Answer (score 8):

A solution using prototypes is only possible when your objects are alike:

```
function Cons(g) { this.good = g; }
Cons.prototype.bad = "something common";
var array = [new Cons("something 1"), new Cons("something 2"), …];
```

But then it's simple (and `O(1)`):

```
delete Cons.prototype.bad;
```

Answer (score 8):

```js
var array = [{"bad": "something", "good":"something"},{"bad":"something", "good":"something"}];

const cleanArray = array.map(item=>{
  delete item.bad
  return item
})
console.log(cleanArray)
```

Answer (score 4):

The shortest way in ES6:

```
array.forEach(e => {delete e.someKey});
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is a bit old now, but I would like to offer an alternative solution that doesn't mutate source data and requires minimal manual effort:

```
function mapOut(sourceObject, removeKeys = []) {
  const sourceKeys = Object.keys(sourceObject);
  const returnKeys = sourceKeys.filter(k => !removeKeys.includes(k));
  let returnObject = {};
  returnKeys.forEach(k => {
    returnObject[k] = sourceObject[k];
  });
  return returnObject;
}

const array = [
  {"bad": "something", "good":"something"},
  {"bad":"something", "good":"something"},
];

const newArray = array.map(obj => mapOut(obj, [ "bad", ]));
```

It's still a little less than perfect, but maintains some level of immutability and has the flexibility to name multiple properties that you want to remove. (Suggestions welcome)

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use `Object.assign` within a `forEach()` loop so that the objects are copied and does not affect the original array of objects

```
var res = [];
array.forEach(function(item) { 
    var tempItem = Object.assign({}, item);
    delete tempItem.bad; 
    res.push(tempItem);
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6:

```
const newArray = array.map(({keepAttr1, keepAttr2}) => ({keepAttr1, newPropName: keepAttr2}))
```

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me!

```
export function removePropertiesFromArrayOfObjects(arr = [], properties = []) {
return arr.map(i => {
    const newItem = {}
    Object.keys(i).map(key => {
        if (properties.includes(key)) { newItem[key] = i[key] }
    })
    return newItem
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of libraries out there. It all depends on how complicated your data structure is (e.g. consider deeply nested keys)

We like [object-fields](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-fields) as it also works with deeply nested hierarchies (build for api fields parameter). Here is a simple code example

```js
// const objectFields = require('object-fields');

const array = [ { bad: 'something', good: 'something' }, { bad: 'something', good: 'something' } ];

const retain = objectFields.Retainer(['good']);
retain(array);
console.log(array);
// => [ { good: 'something' }, { good: 'something' } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-fields@2.0.19"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-fields](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-fields)

Answer (score 0):

By reduce:

```js
const newArray = oldArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { remove_one, remove_two, ...keep_data } = curr;
  acc.push(keep_data);
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [underscore.JS](https://underscorejs.org/) library:

```
let asdf = [{"asd": 12, "asdf": 123}, {"asd": 121, "asdf": 1231}, {"asd": 142, "asdf": 1243}]


_.map(asdf, function (row) {
    return _.omit(row, ['asd'])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic function to remove a property for all objects in an array of objects:

```js
/**
 * Returns the array of objects without the indicated property.
 * @param {array} arrayOfObjects
 * @param {string} property
 * @returns {array}
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69723902 remove property from an array of objects
 * @see https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#objects--rest-spread new object with certain properties omitted
 */
const removePropertyFromArrayOfObjects = (arrayOfObjects, property) => {
    return arrayOfObjects.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
        const {[property]: _new_name_, ...keep_data} = currentValue;
        accumulator.push(keep_data);
        return accumulator;
    }, []);
};


// Example of use:

const array = [{"bad": "something", "good": "something"}, {"bad": "something", "good": "something"}];

console.log(removePropertyFromArrayOfObjects(array, "bad"));

// Expected output: Array [Object { good: "something" }, Object { good: "something" }]
```

Answer (score -5):

```js
var array = [{"bad": "something", "good":"something"},{"bad":"something", "good":"something"}];
var results = array.map(function(item){
  return {good : item["good"]}
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
```

Comment: Could you explain your solution?

Comment: Map is a new data structure in JavaScript ES6. Attached link might help you. https://hackernoon.com/what-you-should-know-about-es6-maps-dc66af6b9a1e

Comment: this solution isn't good if you have many props in your items.

Comment: Yes! Tried to provide a different approach.

Comment: In your comment, you're confusing `Map`, the data structure which you're not using, with `Array.prototype.map`, the array method, which you're using.