# How to remove an element from array of literal objects

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm trying to remove the actions property from each object within the array data:

```
[{productName: "", ... action: ...,}, {productName: "", ...action:...} ...]
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133635/javascript-remove-attribute-for-all-objects-in-array

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr  =[{productName: "bbbb", action: 'b'},
         {productName: "aa",action: 'a'}, 
         {productName: "tt",action: 't'}, 
         {productName: "vv",action: 'v'}]


arr = arr.map((d) => {delete d.action ; return d;});
```

Answer (score 1):

1) With `map(...)`:

```
your_array.map(o => {'productName': o.productName})
```

*NB that this is more elegant if you want to filter off lots of attributes, but more work if you just want to remove one.*

2) With `delete`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < your_array.length; i++){
    delete your_array[i].action
}
```

Comment: You're deleting productName in the second one. The first one also removes more than just 'action', which may not be what is wanted.

Comment: @Blam Nice spot, I've updated the second and added a note to the first. I left the first method as it may be desirable if you just wish to keep one key, value pair of many.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the array using `map` and [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) the object to keep only the required field

```js
var arr = [{
  producet: 'xyz',
  action: 'abc',
  other: 'o'
}, {
  producet: 'xyz',
  action: '123',
  other: 'o'
}, {
  producet: 'xyz',
  action: 'sdf',
  other: 'o'
}]
const result = arr.map(({
  action,
  ...rest
}) => rest);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation

Answer (score 1):

With ES6 you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to separate out the object properties you want to retain, and the part you want to discard:

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  productName: "1",
  action: ''
}, {
  id: 1,
  productName: "2",
  action: ''
}];

let out = data.map(({ action, ...rest }) => rest);
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array `map` It will return a new array.Inside `map` callback create a new object and populate only those fields that are required. Don't mutate the original array

```js
var arr = [{
  productName: "1",
  action: ''
}, {
  productName: "2",
  action: ''
}];


let newArr = arr.map(function(item) {
  return Object.assign({}, {
    productName: item.productName
  })
});
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: What if `productName` isn't the only property?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) you can use the `delete` operator.

A simple way to do this is to loop over your array `arr` and delete the property from each object.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    delete arr[i].action;
}
```

This approach [is slightly faster](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-performance-test-for-vs-for-each-vs-map-reduce-filter-find-32c1113f19d7) than other approaches such as `map` and `for each`.