# Removing attribute from an Object Array by key string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js

I have an array of objects, I want to remove a few properties of this object, by calling a function and passing the array and the key I want to delete.

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46839399/10888237) answer on Stack Overflow and it works when I specify the key manually, like `id`. It deletes the `id` property of each object in the array.

```
const newArray = array.map(
            ({
                id,
                ...otherAttributes
            }) => otherAttributes
        );
```

But when I pass the key to the function, and then use the key from the parameter, it is not able to detect the key in the object and so not able to delete it. The function body is something like this:

```
removeKeyFromObjectsArray(newArray, key) {           
        const newArray = products.map(
            ({
                key,
                ...otherAttributes
            }) => otherAttributes
        );
        return newArray;
```

I call this function using `this.removeKeyFromObjectsArray(this.updatedProducts, 'id')` but the objects inside this array still has the key. (The `this` is because it's inside a Vue App and I need to refer to a different function in the same instance).

This function works if we manually specify the key name like `id` but it does not work when we pass the key string through a parameter and then use it, can someone explain what is the issue here and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use [computed property names in destrcuturing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring), you need to wrap `key` with `[]` and assign it to a new variable (`_` in this case). Otherwise, it will destructure a property called `"key"` from the object and not a property with the *value* in the `key` variable

```js
function removeKeyFromObjectsArray(products, key) {
    const newArray = products.map(
      ({
        [key]: _,
        ...otherAttributes
      }) => otherAttributes
    );
    return newArray;
}

console.log(
  removeKeyFromObjectsArray([{ id: 1, name: 'name1'},
                            { id: 2, name: 'name2'}], 'name')
)
```

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky how?

Comment: Now it's better :)

Answer (score 1):

That's removing the literal `key` - use dynamic property notation with square brackets `[]` to get the result you want:

```
const newArray = products.map(({ [key]: _, ...otherAttributes }) => otherAttributes);
```

The reason I'm assigning the unwanted key to `_` above is because it's convention to use `_` as an "unwanted" or "ignore this" key. Note that this is different to *prefixing* the key with `_` (`_key`) which means "don't modify this directly - use getters or setters instead".