# return array objects with some of the properties in the objects. Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

let's say I have an array called 'radicados' like this:

```
this.radicados = [{
      id:0,
      asunto:'Facturas ADPRO Propias',
      consecutivo:'FAC-AB-00046',
      documentos: [{id:1, descripcion:'documento1.pdf', esAnexo:false, ruta:'' },
                   {id:2, descripcion:'documento2.xls', esAnexo:false, ruta:'' },
                   {id:3, descripcion:'documento3.doc', esAnexo:true,  ruta:'' }]
    },{
      id:1,
      asunto:'Contrato de Construcciones',
      consecutivo:'CR-093132',
      documentos: [{id:1, descripcion:'documento4.pdf', esAnexo:false, ruta:''},
                   {id:2, descripcion:'documento5.jpg', esAnexo:false, ruta:''},
                   {id:3, descripcion:'documento6.doc', esAnexo:true,  ruta:''},
                   {id:3, descripcion:'documento7.pdf', esAnexo:true,  ruta:''}]
    }]
```

Is there a way to return an array with all the elements but without the documents properties in Typescript? Like this:

```
this.radicados2 = [{
      id:0,
      asunto:'Facturas ADPRO Propias',
      consecutivo:'FAC-AB-00046'
    },{
      id:1,
      asunto:'Contrato de Construcciones',
      consecutivo:'CR-093132'
    }]
```

I'm saving all the array but I don´t want to have the 'documentos' property always because I only use it in One moment. I know I could itereate over the array and create a new one where I onle save the properties I need, but I would like to see if there is an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Remove property for all objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133635/remove-property-for-all-objects-in-array)

```
var result = radicados.map(({documentos, ...elem}) => elem)
```

If you'd like to learn more about it , you can check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Nice. I was thinking about destructuring the other props and returning a new object but this looks nicer

Comment: You might want to include some reference to "destructuring assignment" in this answer (your linked answer just `delete`s things).  e.g., [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) page

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks for improving the answer quality.