# How to remove a key in object in array

Tags: reactjs

I have an address that looks like this

```
let address = [{"_id":"6013a6ef20f06428741cf53c","address01":"123","address02":"512","postcode":"23","state":"512","country":"32","key":1},{"_id":"6013a6eh6012428741cf53c","address01":"512","address02":"6","postcode":"6612","state":"33","country":"512","key":2}]
```

How can I remove '_id' and 'key' together with its Key and Value Pair.

And can you please let me know how does this type of array is called? Is it called Object in Array? I keep seeing this type of array but I have no clue how to deal with this, is there like a cheatsheet to deal with?

Comment: It's an array of objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove property for all objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133635/remove-property-for-all-objects-in-array)

Comment: You can loop through the array with a ```forEach``` then use the ```delete``` operator to. delete the key/value pair you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the property of the object like this:

```
address[0]["_id"]
// or
address[0]._id
```

and you can delete the property like this:

```
delete address[0]["_id"]
// or
delete address[0]._id
```

Where `0` is the 1st index of the array. You might need to iterate over your array and remove the property from each object:

```
address.forEach(a => {
    delete a._id;
    delete a.key;
});
```

Comment: Hi, it is returning
TypeError: address.forEach is not a function,

Why is that?

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for your time, I've checked it, typeof address is string instead of object, it must be because I've JSON.stringify it before, however, if its currently string, how can I change it back to object?

Comment: You can't do much with a string. Use `JSON.parse(address)` to convert it back.

Answer (score 1):

First, this type of array is called "Array of Objects" (objects inside array)

Second, you can generate new set of array by delete the key which you want to remove by,

```
let newSetOfArray = address.map((obj)=> {
    delete obj._id;
    delete obj.key;
    return obj;
});

console.log(newSetOfArray);    // this array of objects has keys with absence of _id & key.
```