# How to parse only specific attributes from a JSON file to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have this JSON array:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "pnome": "dasda",
      "unome": "dad",
      "avatar": 1,
      "email": "d",
      "pass": "password",
      "ponto": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "pnome": "Enguias",
      "unome": "Enguias outra vez",
      "avatar": 10,
      "email": "enguias@enguias.enguias",
      "pass": "enguias",
      "ponto": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "pnome": "André",
      "unome": "Marques",
      "avatar": 1,
      "email": "aglmarque@gmail.com",
      "pass": "yet1",
      "ponto": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

And i'm putting it into an array with axios, like this:

```
    axios.get(my_url_api)
    .then((res)=>{
        const txt = JSON.stringify(res.data.data);
        const users = JSON.parse(txt)
    })
```

Which makes the users array have all the info in the JSON file. How can I make it so that I only pass specific attributes like email and pass? It would look like this:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "email": "d",
      "pass": "password"
    },
    {
      "email": "enguias@enguias.enguias",
      "pass": "enguias"
    },
    {
      "email": "aglmarque@gmail.com",
      "pass": "yet1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why are you stringifying data that came directly from JSON? and then immediately parsing it again?

Comment: Yes, you can just do `const users = res.data.data`. Also, it's not a JSON array. It's JSON (text), which is parsed into an array by axios. Understanding this distinction will make it easier to realize when you actually need JSON.stringify and JSON.parse (you very often don't). All this if completely irrelevant anyway though; this is about removing properties from the objects in an array.

Comment: Duplicate: [Remove property for all objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133635/remove-property-for-all-objects-in-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.map()` function to remove the unnecessary fields like following example:

```js
let res = {
"data": [
{
"id": 6,
"pnome": "dasda",
"unome": "dad",
"avatar": 1,
"email": "d",
"pass": "password",
"ponto": 0
},
{
"id": 3,
"pnome": "Enguias",
"unome": "Enguias outra vez",
"avatar": 10,
"email": "enguias@enguias.enguias",
"pass": "enguias",
"ponto": 0
},
{
"id": 2,
"pnome": "André",
"unome": "Marques",
"avatar": 1,
"email": "aglmarque@gmail.com",
"pass": "yet1",
"ponto": 0
}
]
}

res.data = res.data.map(item => {
  return {
  email: item.email,
  pass: item.pass
  };
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: One-liner with destructuring: `res.data = res.data.map(({ email, pass }) => ({ email, pass })`

Comment: If you immediately know the answer, it's very likely a duplicate. Please check first.