# How can I remove a property from an object in an array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array in my Vue component that I'm trying to parse out in a method, but I don't want the ID in it at all. I want the array to be the same as it is currently but only show the option index, not the id.

Is there a way, within the method, that I can pop the ID index out of the array entirely?

```js
var vm = 
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    options: [
      {id:100, option:"1 - John Doe"},
      {id:200, option:"2 - Jane Doe"}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    getNames(){
      
      let names = this.options;
      
      console.log(names);
    }
  }
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<button @click="getNames()">TEST</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you consume the condensed options or what is the planed purpose for `getNames`? Asking because Vue.js might have a simpler solution to achieve rendering, filtering, templating, etc. (usually you keep original data in model and use what you need in the view (benefit and strength of MVC / MVVM).

Comment: Although requiring "but I don't want the ID in it at all", you [accepted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70963354/5730279) which has the ID property remapped as`id: option.option`. Please clarify your question (give an example of wanted output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the array and create another array

```js
var vm = 
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    options: [
      {id:100, option:"1 - John Doe"},
      {id:200, option:"2 - Jane Doe"}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    getNames(){
      
      let names = this.options.map(option => {
        return { 
          option: option.option
        }
      });
      
      console.log(names);
    }
  }
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<button @click="getNames()">TEST</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```js
var vm = 
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    options: [
      {id:100, option:"1 - John Doe"},
      {id:200, option:"2 - Jane Doe"}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    getNames(){
      
      let names = this.options.map(o => o.option);
      
      console.log(names);
    }
  }
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<button @click="getNames()">TEST</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a **pure JavaScript** task. It is solvable independently from VueJS or any other framework.

In general you can apply two approaches (either keep what is needed or remove what is obsolete):

1. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): to transform each source element to the new target format; returns a new array
2. [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete): to remove the unwanted property from the original array

```js
let options: [
  {id:100, option:"1 - John Doe"},
  {id:200, option:"2 - Jane Doe"}
];

// to get a new (simple) array of strings
let strings = options.map(o => o.option);
console.log(strings);

// to get the same array with nested objects where property was removed
options.forEach(o => delete o.id);
console.log(options);
```

See also:
[Remove property for all objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133635/remove-property-for-all-objects-in-array)